# How can I can log cpu spikes?

Tags: linux, process

I will be running a custom daemon that could potentially spike the server's cpu? Is there a way to log those spikes with their start and running time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If youre running linux or other unix variant, there is `sar` which is installed by default in many distributions. Many times it runs from cron on a defined interval, however you can also run it manually with a specified polling interval

For example:

> sar -u 1 0

This will run sar once a second forever. The `-u` tells it to output the CPU usage info, the `1` is how many seconds between polls, and the `0` is how many times to poll (0 for forever).

It can also watch a specific process with the `-x` parameter. It can also log its data to a file for later viewing. Sar can do a lot, so consult the man page if you want to do more.

Comment: This is typically what we do too, because it is really quite easy to get it running.  The one point is that it takes a snapshot of that point in time.  So as long as you are doing them pretty frequently, it isn't a problem.  If you bump the interval up to 5 or 10 minutes, you may miss the time when the app is actually spiking.

Answer (score 2):

Use any monitoring system(Cacti,Zabbix,Munin,...) for monitoring daemon memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cacti:

http://www.cacti.net/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you have a bunch of servers to monitor, get a "utility server" and take the time and setup munin (what I use), or cacti or zenoss or ganglia or whatever you like.

But if it's a one-off server, go with sar, which is part of the sysstat suite.  Usually it's run from cron.  In Debian systems, you'll have to enable it in /etc/defaults/sysstat.  You can graph the results with ksar.