# How do I log when CPU usage is over 40% per process

Tags: ubuntu

I have a problem with my server. Once in a while the CPU spikes to 100% and the server crashes and then needs to be rebooted.

I've tried to go through my current logs but no luck.

I would like to log every time a process uses more then say 40% of my CPU.

I've read about a sar solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/229253/how-can-i-can-log-cpu-spikes):

```
sar -u 1 0
```

but that doesn't have a treshold for what to log.

Idealy this would be something that runs continously so that I can see after the next time the server crashes what actually caused the crash!

**Specs:**

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
CPU: 1 Core(s) 2048MB
CPU Flags: advcpu,acpi,pae,virtblk,virtio
```

Answer (score 0):

based on results from:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux

The I would install mpstat program, from that Based on a few user suggestions:

```
mpstat | grep -A 5 "%idle" | tail -n 1 | awk -F " " '{print 100 -  $ 12}'a
```

This will give you total CPU usage, you could then use that as a safe threshold in a script to take action.

EDIT:
Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :

do PROC= ` mpstat | grep -A 5 "%idle" | tail -n 1 | awk -F " " '{print 100 -  $ 12}'a` if [$PROC > 55]; then    PS ua >> log.txt echo "---------" >> log.txt fi

Sleep 1 done
```

to gain a log.

Comment: @EEAA Thanks for the assist. Apparently I was a little loopy last night, on my drive to work i was just thinking I had some errors. Though you've made it better still than I would have.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of luck using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) for logging and alerting when server issues arise.

For example, you could specify the following in your config file to alert and log if a process exceeds 40% CPU usage:

```
if cpu is greater than 40% for 5 cycles then alert
```